APK Size Doubled Despite No Changes to lib and assets Folders
I recently received a release for my Android app that was 90 MB. However, the latest release has doubled in size, despite no changes to the lib and assets files. but the raw size of same files are doubled
I've compared the two APKs, and the contents of the lib and assets folders are identical. Additionally, there have been no changes to the proguard_rules.txt file or the build.gradle files.
Does anyone know what could be causing this sudden increase in APK size?
Thank you!
here's two apk analyze's comparison:



Can you also confirm that it was built in the same way? Is this latest version just an unoptimized debug built?

Android apps today usually save .so files uncompressed in APK as the .so files can then be directly used from within APK and don't have to be extracted when you install the APK  on a Android phone.

I rollbacked to my previous version and changing min SDK from 21 to 31 was the cause, changing the min SDK downto 21 decreased app size by half.
here's why:
Whether to use the legacy convention of compressing all dex files in the APK. If null, dex files will be uncompressed when minSdk >= 28.

This property does not affect dex file compression in APKs produced from app bundles.


it's an answer, the causation i found

The APK Analyzer displays the zipped file size which otherwise can be referred to as the raw file size of every entity and the size of the download file as illustrated in the following figure.


Raw File Size : The performer’s relevance to the size of the complete APK file. 

Download Size : This information gives the possible Google Playmall compressed size of the given entity as it will be delivered.


The Total Download Size Rank reflects the rank order of the above mentioned Total Download Size while as the % of Total Download Size presents the proportion the particular entity contributes to the Total Download Size of the given APK.
Check this link for more information.
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/apk-analyzer
